# How to get an overloaded == operator to work with LINQ and EF Core?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, operator-overloading, equals

so basically, I have a project which uses EF Core. In order to shorten my lambdas when comparing if two objects (class Protocol) are equal, I've overridden my Equals method and overloaded the == and != operators. However, LINQ doesn't seem to care about it, and still uses reference for determining equality. Thanks

As I've said before, I've overridden the Equals method and overloaded the == and != operators. With no luck. I've also tried implementing the IEquatable interface. Also no luck.

I am using:
EF Core 2.2.4

//the protocol class

```
[Key]
public int ProtocolId {get;set;}
public string Repnr {get;set;}
public string Service {get;set;}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj is Protocol other)
    {
        return this.Equals(other);
    }
    return false;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return $"{Repnr}-{Service}".GetHashCode();
}

public bool Equals(Protocol other)
{
    return this?.Repnr == other?.Repnr && this?.Service == other?.Service;
}

public static bool operator ==(Protocol lhs, Protocol rhs)
{
    return lhs.Equals(rhs);
}

public static bool operator !=(Protocol lhs, Protocol rhs)
{
    return !lhs.Equals(rhs);
}
```

//the problem

```
using (var db = new DbContext())
{

     var item1 = new Protocol() { Repnr = "1666", Service = "180" };
     db.Protocols.Add(item1 );
     db.SaveChanges();
     var item2 = new Protocol() { Repnr = "1666", Service = "180" };
     var result1 = db.Protocols.FirstOrDefault(a => a == item2);
     var result2 = db.Protocols.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Equals(item2));
     //both result1 and result2 are null

}
```

I would expect both result1 and result2 to be item1. However, they're both null. I know I could just do a.Repnr == b.Repnr && a.Service == b.Service, but that just isn't as clean. Thanks

Comment: Since this is linq-to-sql (or EF) and not linq-to-objects (in memory), the expression is translated into SQL that can be executed by the database instead of the client. But your operator and overloads cannot be translated into SQL. The db can't execute your (client-side) `==` operator.

Comment: You cannot do that, you will have to grab the objects into memory and execute it as an in-memory query.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in EF Core. Normally, EF Core should detect that the predicate cannot be translated to SQL (as @RenéVogt told), and execute the predicate on the client instead.

Comment: @Georg Which would suffer the performance. Client evaluation concept has been considered to be a mistake, and [will be removed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client) in the next major EF Core version, so you'd better not rely on it.

Comment: @IvanStoev Sure, it is a performance nightmare to download and transform all objects just to go over everyone of them on the client and therefore, yes, it does make sense if this concept is removed in EF Core (I did not know that), but then EF Core should throw an exception rather than returning a wrong result. EF Core can detect that because the expression will tell that it is an overloaded equality expression.

Comment: Thank you all for your awesome and quick responses. I get it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To understand why the incorrect equality comparer is used, you have to be aware about the difference between `IEnumerable<...>` and `IQueryable<...>`.

### IEnumerable

An object that implements `IEnumerable<...>`, is an object that represents a sequence of similar objects. It holds everything to fetch the first item of the sequence, and once you've got an item of the sequence you can get the next item, as long as there is a next item.

You start enumerating either explicitly by calling `GetEnumerator()` and repeatedly call `MoveNext()`. More common is to start enumerating implicitly by using `foreach`, or LINQ terminating statements like `ToList()`, `ToDictionary()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `Count()` or `Any()`. This group of LINQ methods internally uses either `foreach`, or `GetEnumerator()` and `MoveNext()` / `Current`.

### IQueryable

An object that implements `IQueryable<...>` also represents an enumerable sequence. The difference however, is that this sequence usually is not held by your process, but by a different process, like a database management system.

The IQueryable does not (necessarily) hold everything to enumerate. Instead it holds an `Expression` and a `Provider`. The `Expression` is a generic description about what must be queried. The `Provider` knows which process will execute the query (usually a database management system) and  how to communicate with this process (usually something SQL-like).

An `IQueryable<..>` also implements `IEnumerable<..>`, so you can start enumerating the sequence as if it was a standard IEnumerable. Once you start enumerating an `IQueryable<...>` by calling (internally) `GetEnumerator()`, the `Expression` is sent to the `Provider`, who translates the `Expression` into SQL and executes the query. The result is presented as an enumerator, which can be enumerated using `MoveNext()` / `Current`.

This means, that if you want to enumerate an `IQueryable<...>`, the `Expression` must be translated into a language that the `Provider` supports. As the compiler does not really know who will execute the query, the compiler can't complain if your Expression holds methods or classes that your Provider doesn't know how to translate to SQL. In such cases you'll get a run-time error.

It is easy to see, that SQL does not know your own defined `Equals` method. In fact, there are even several standard LINQ functions that are not supported. See [Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (LINQ to Entities)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities).

**So what should I do if I want to use an unsupported function?**

One of the things that you could do is move the data to your local process, and then call the unsupported function.

This can be done using `ToList`, but if you will only use one or a few of the fetched items, this would be a waste of processing power.

> One of the slower parts of a database query is the transport of the selected data to your local process. Hence it is wise to limit the data to the data that you actually plan to use.

A smarter solution would be to use `AsEnumerable`. This will fetch the selected data "per page". It will fetch the first page, and once you've enumerated through the fetched page (using MoveNext), it will fetch the next page.

So if you only use a few of the fetched items, you will have fetched some items that are not used, but at least you won't have fetched all of them.

**Example**

Suppose you have a local function that takes a `Student` as input and returns a Boolean

```
bool HasSpecialAbility(Student student);
```

Requirement: give me three Students that live in New York City that have the special Ability.

Alas, `HasSpecialAbility` is a local function, it can't be translated into Sql. You'll have to get the Students to your local process before calling it.

```
var result = dbContext.Students
    // limit the transported data as much as you can:
    .Where(student => student.CityCode == "NYC")

    // transport to local process per page:
    .AsEnumerable()

    // now you can call HasSpecialAbility:
    .Where(student => HasSpecialAbility(student))
    .Take(3)
    .ToList();
```

Ok, you might have fetched a page of 100 Students while you only needed 3, but at least you haven't fetched all 25000 students.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! I've been wondering about this exact thing for a while now. Never really knew what the difference between IEnumerable and IQueryable was. Now I do. Thank you again and have a great day, Michal.